# Create a desktop shortcut in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net

It baffles me that there is still no way to create something as simple as a desktop shortcut directly in .NET Framework (C#) that I know if.  Up until now I have used the Windows Script Host Object Model COM objects.

I need to do something similar now in .NET Standard.  Is there a way to create a desktop shortcut or get the properties of one in a .NET Standard 2.1 library?

Comment: See the 2nd answer in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at it.  If I am going to write to the file directly I probably need to figure out the other parts of the file structure.  Like the arguments and working directory etc.